# Javascript: Redirect page onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm fiddling around with a pretend "Logon screen" but am having trouble when it comes to redirecting the page.

I've tried a couple of different suggestions that I've found on the site, but so far nothing has worked.

I honestly think I'm just doing it wrong.

Any advice?

**HTML**

```
<div class="title"><h1>Webby Site</h1></div>
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form">
      <input id="User" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input id="PWord" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button class="button">Login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a>Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.button').click(function(){
            if ($('input#User').val() === "1" && $('input#PWord').val() === "1"){
            document.location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
            } else {
                alert('Incorrect Account Details');
            }
        });
    });
```

Code I've tried (in the same area as `document.location.href`)

1. `document.location`
2. `window.location`
3. `window.location.href`
4. `location.href`

Comment: Could you reproduce this problem at JSFiddle, please?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev unfortunately, while it works okay otherwise in Chrome, it doesn't work at all in JSFiddle. I get "{"error": "Please use POST request"}". But I can make one anyway, if it would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `button` acts like `input type="submit"`, so it's trying to submit your form. Use `event.preventDefault()` to avoid this behaviour.

Correct way to redirect is setting `window.location.href`.

Also, I strongly recommend not to try client-side authentification, because anyone could just read login and password in your js file.

Comment: Ahh, that's where I went wrong. Thanks!
And yeah, as I put in the question, it's only a "pretend" login page. I don't have the knowledge to build a real one (yet :P), plus this is just for personal fun and learning. Not the WWW!

Answer (score 0):

For HTML, you can use `<button onclick="location.href='url'">text</button>`

You can also use `<button onclick="window.location.replace(url)">text</button>`